# Angular service being called twice

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-services

I have the following angular service:

```
appServices.factory('AuthenticationService', function () {
    var auth = {
        isLogged: false
    }

    return auth;
})
```

and this `TokenInterceptor` service:

```
appServices.factory('TokenInterceptor', function ($q, $window, AuthenticationService) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
        },

        response: function (response) {
            console.log(AuthenticationService.isLogged)
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
});
```

which I push into the `$httpProvider`

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
```

And

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/index',
            controller: IndexCtrl,
            access: { requiredLogin: true }
        })
```

After login in `AuthenticationService.isLogged = true`, and if I navigate to route "/" through agular buttons everything is ok, but when page is refreshed the AuthenticationService is instantiated again, and I can see that `console.log(AuthenticationService.isLogged)` prints `false` and inmediately after prints `true` so page navigates back to "/login".

Why is it printing false -> true? What can I do to keep authentication state after refresh?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all your answers. On the comments of the authentication [tutorial](http://www.kdelemme.com/2014/03/09/authentication-with-angularjs-and-a-node-js-rest-api/) I was following someone mentioned the same problem. I ended up understanding that their approach was a little cumbersome. The `AuthenticationService` doesn't do much more than checking the existence of a token in `$window.sessionStorage.token`, so you were all right about using some sort of storage.

I ended up just doing:

```
appServices.factory('AuthenticationService', function () {
    isLogged: function () {
        return $window.sessionStorage.token == true
    }    
})
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at ngStorage, or some kind of storage mechanism..

Comment: @PSL I don't think that's the point here.I was thinking more in a way of waiting for the second isLoggein = true or trying to avoid the isLoggein = false.

Comment: Sorry mybad. I dint read it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads you're initializing it to `false` at.

```
var auth = {
    isLogged: false
};
```

So when you set it to true after login with

```
AuthenticationService.isLogged = true;
```

That's fine, until you naviage away and your javascript context is lost and everything starts over again, at which point it is once again false.

You're already using sessionStorage so you might as well stick with that, i.e. something like:

```
AuthenticationService.isLogged = true;
$window.sessionStorage.isLogged = "yeah";
```

Then replace your initializer with

```
var auth = {
    isLogged: $window.sessionStorage.isLogged == "yeah" ? true : false
};
```

This is a simple example, I'd probably put a setLoggedIn or something like that on your service, which does the sessionStorage setting so you have it in one place.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
function init($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

    }
}
```

And add .run(init) to your angular declaration at the bottom of your app :

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(config)
    .run(init)
```

It will be called after every navigator refresh. You can store your data in $window.sessionStorage and test it after each refresh.